# React mongoose validation failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to store order data but getting following error when adding it to mongoose:

**Request:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Here is my source Code:

placeOrder Handler:

```
const placeOrderHandler = () => {
    dispatch(
      createOrder({
        orderItems: cartItems,
        shippingAddress: {
          address: shippingAddress.address,
          city: shippingAddress.city,
          postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode,
          country: shippingAddress.country,
        },
        paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
        itemPrice: cart.itemPrice,
        shippingPrice: cart.shippingPrice,
        taxPrice: cart.taxPrice,
        totalPrice: cart.totalPrice,
      })
    );
  };
```

**orderModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

module.exports = Order;
```

If I am not wrong it is throwing error on **orderItems:**, but I am sending *array of objects* data which I have already defined in my **orderModel.js**.

Comment: Yow items schema has a product property which is required, but if you look at the items sended by the client there is no product property there is one called productID and product !== productID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ernesto mentioned I was writing **product** in my schema instead of **productID**. Here is the correct way:

```
orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        productID: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
```